# mySQL sub-query causing Unknown column error

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a database. One has a list of accounts with various datapoints by account (fix_cost_summary). The second table has all trades done by all accounts and the commissions associated with the trades (comm_table). I am trying to run a query to output all columns from fix_cost_summary and a sum of commissions by account from comm_table.

My subquery is causing an "Unknown Column" error. Please let me know if there is an error in my code.

```
SELECT 
      fix_cost_summary.*,
     comm_table.Short_Name, 
     (SELECT SUM(Commissions) 
        FROM
             comm_table     
        GROUP BY 
             comm_table.Short_Name)
FROM
     fix_cost_summary,
     comm_table
WHERE 
     fix_cost_summary.Short_Name = comm_table.Short_name
```

Comment: Are you sure all columns actually exist? [This seems to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f407f/1).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: But as soon as there are records with multiple `Short_Name` values in `comm_table`, the subquery will return multiple results which will produce [`ER_TOO_MANY_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_too_many_rows) (albeit not the error cited by the OP).

Comment: @eggyal Touché, I was only attempting to reproduce the error in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Short_Name` is unique in `fix_cost_summary`, MySQL will allow you to simply join the tables and then group on that column:

```
SELECT   fix_cost_summary.*, SUM(comm_table.Commissions)
FROM     fix_cost_summary JOIN comm_table USING (Short_Name)
GROUP BY Short_Name
```

Comment: IF I wanted to add a WHERE clause to the SUM command, how would I do that? I want to SUM(comm_table.Commissions) for a date range comm_table.Date > X and comm_table.Date < Y

Comment: @Steve: Add your `WHERE` clause just before the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: There are some accounts listed in the fix_cost_summary table that are not in the comm_table (accounts that haven't done any commissions). I still want them to show up in the result. I made it a `LEFT JOIN` which I thought would solve it but it hasn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, you have the correct idea with a `LEFT JOIN`, but you will need to move the filter (currently in your new `WHERE` clause) into the `JOIN` criteria: change `USING (Short_Name)` to `ON fix_cost_summary.Short_Name = comm_table.Short_Name AND comm_table.Date > X AND comm_table.Date < Y`; you will then also need to qualify the reference to `Short_Name` with a table name in the `GROUP BY` clause: `GROUP BY fix_cost_summary.Short_Name`.  Note that you can make the whole thing somewhat less verbose by aliasing the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The inline subquery will return more than 1 rows. One way to solve this, is to change it into a derived table:

```
SELECT 
      f.*,
      c.Sum_Commisions
FROM
      fix_cost_summary AS f
   JOIN
      ( SELECT Short_Name,
               SUM(Commissions) AS Sum_Commisions
        FROM
               comm_table     
        GROUP BY 
               Short_Name
      ) AS c 
         ON c.Short_Name = f.Short_Name ;
```

Comment: You're missing the join condition.

Comment: @Barmar thnx. It didn't look right when I posted but I couldn't figure out why ...